# Jumping between applications on STM32F1

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, stm32, qemu

## Background

I am trying to implement jumping between applications on a STM32F1 microcontroller. I am using qemu (provided by GNU MCU Eclipse) to emulate the Olimex-H103 board which uses the STM32F103RBT6 microcontroller. I am using a "blue pill" I bought on ebay to test it on actual hardware. The blue pill is equipped with a STM32F103C8T6 microcontroller. The two microcontrollers are very similar and even share datasheets from some sources.

[image: STM32F103RBT6 Header board]
*STM32F103RBT6 Olimex header board*

[image: STM32F103C8T6 BluePill]
*STM32F103C8T6 BluePill*

My applications are one main application which loads a second one into memory and then jumps to it. The main application is compiled and linked as a default STM32F1 project by GNU MCU Eclipse while the second one is a C program compiled and linked with a linking script (just specifying memory locations and sizes), so no alignment for a vector table. The second application is bundled with the main application a s a char array which is copied into memory. The main application also has a lookup table for applications that is to be exposed to the secondary application.

```
void hello_world();

unsigned int lookup_table[] = {
      (unsigned int)&hello_world
};
```

After the secondary application is placed in memory (and it is verified to have been properly copied) the main application jumps to it and passes a reference to its lookup table:

```
typedef int(*AppFunc)(unsigned int);
// Application is compiled with -mthumb, hence the +1 to the address
AppFunc appFunc = (AppFunc)(((uint32_t)0x20003000) + 1);
appFunc((unsigned int)&lookup_table);
```

The secondary application should then be able to call functions, from the references in the lookup table.

```
void start(unsigned int *lookup_table)
{
    typedef void(*void_f)();
    static void_f hello_func = (void_f)*(lookup_table);

    hello_func();
}
```

When the application is finished the execution should return to the main application (as the return address is on the stack?).

**To clarify:** I do not (currently) change vector table or stack pointer, since I would want these to be consistent (if possible).

---

## Problem

This all works fine with qemu but not with real hardware. In qemu it jumps to the second applcication, execute functions in the main application and when finished it jumps back to the main application. However, on the actual hardware it stalls after the jump if start() calls methods from the lookup table, otherwise it works fine (empty start()) but I want to be able to jump back into the main application and execute functions there.

Is this a bug in qemu that makes it work? Is it a hardware issue or could it be the code? I don't really understand where the problem lies since qemu runs the applications flawlessly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your branch destination at 0x20003000 or is your table at 0x20003000 and the address is an item in the table?

Comment: save yourself headaches and think OR one not PLUS one, in this case either is fine if that is the destination address for a branch

Comment: It doesnt look to me like you need to set the lsbit of the table address, instead hello_world should already have the lsbit set, but depends on the tool and how you invoked, it, etc.  Possible that qemu doesnt actually look at the lsbit (and thus executes fine) so examine the table, disassemble, and see what you see.

Comment: Portability remark: 1) a pointer is not guaranteed to fit into an `int`, 2) a function pointer is not guaranteed to fit into a data pointer. If you enable all warnings and set them to errors, a reasonable compiler [should warn you](https://godbolt.org/g/cNujBU).

Answer (score 1):

Does the linker of the second application know where it's being placed in memory? You can't link it as though it will be run from flash, then copy it to a different address space and expect it to work correctly.

The first location in the vector table is the address of the top of the stack. You need to change `AppFunc appFunc = (AppFunc)(((uint32_t)0x20003000) + 1);` to `AppFunc appFunc = (AppFunc)(((uint32_t)0x20003004));` to get the address of the reset handler.

You don't need to +1 the address, that's handled for you by the compiler. The address you have there is a pointer to where the reset vector is.

Comment: Never +1 the address anyway, if in doubt or the tools dont help use OR rather than ADD.  In this case though the address had to have the lsbit set or it wont work on a cortex-m so when hardcoding you have to get that bit set somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following function for cortex

```
typedef void (application_t)(void);

typedef struct vector
{
    uint32_t        stack_addr;     // intvec[0] is initial Stack Pointer
    application_t*   func_p;        // intvec[1] is initial Program Counter
} vector_t;

void jump_to(const uint32_t addr)
{
    const vector_t* vector_p = (vector_t*)addr;

    // TODO peripheral deinit

    /* Disable interrupt */
    NVIC->ICER[0]=0xFFFFFFFF;
    NVIC->ICPR[0]=0xFFFFFFFF;
#if defined(__NRF_NVIC_ISER_COUNT) && __NRF_NVIC_ISER_COUNT == 2
    NVIC->ICER[1]=0xFFFFFFFF;
    NVIC->ICPR[1]=0xFFFFFFFF;
#endif

    /* Set new vector table */
    SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)addr;

    /* Jump, used asm to avoid stack optimization */
    asm("\n\
        msr msp, %0; \n\
        bx %1;" : : "r"(vector_p->stack_addr), "r"(vector_p->func_p));
}
```